# How to make redirect from one html page to another html

Tags: javascript, html

I had created an Single page application. Basically, I created an HTML page that accepts the input from the user and calls the Javascript which makes an ajax call to rest service. After returning the response I am appending the data to the table and displaying the result in the same page. But now I want the input text box in one page and tables to be displayed on another page. How can I acheive it?

My HTML Code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
   <style>
   .ApplicationName{
     font-family: 'Times New Roman';
     font-style: normal;
     font-size:40px;
     color: rgba(66,138,201,1);
     height:38px;
     width:auto;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-left: 380px;
     text-align:center;
    }
   table{
     font-family:arial,sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     width:100%
    }
   td,th{
     border:1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 20px;
   }
   #table {
     margin-left: -850px;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
   <body>
    <div class ="container" style="background-color: rgba(66,138,201,1)">
            <div class ="navbar-header">
            <p  class="ApplicationName" style="color: white;">JIRA-STATUS TRACKER</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="row">

                  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                     <label for="name">Search by Manager</label>

    <input type="managerid" class="form-control" id="ManagerId"   type ="text" autocomplete="off"  maxlength="8" onkeyup="alphanumOnly(this)" placeholder="ManagerId"></input>
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 3px;" onclick="getReporteeList(); this.disabled = true;" >Submit</button></a>
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 3px;" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()"></input>   

   </div>
    <br>
    <div id ="table" style="display:none">
            <div class="container text-center" >
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                       <div class="panel panel-primary">
                       <div class="panel-heading" >Reportees  List</div>
    <table id = "employee_table" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>UserId</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                </tr>

            </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id ="jiratable" style="display:none"> 
            <div class="container text-center" >
                    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 220%;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">JIRA - List</div>
                    <table class="table table-hover">   
            <table id = "Jira_table"  class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0" style="width:220%;table-layout:fixed">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="80">Number</th>
                                <th>JiraNumber</th>
                                <th>JiraStatus</th>
                                <th>EmailId</th>
                            </tr>  
                           </thead> 
              </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <html>
</html>
```

My Javascript code:

```
            function getReporteeList() {
            var name = document.getElementById('ManagerId').value;
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            console.log(start);
        $.ajax({

           url:'http://localhost:8088/JirasTrackingApp/reporter/
          Reportees/ReporteeList/'+ $("#ManagerId").val(),
           type:'GET',
         "crossDomain": true,

          dataType: 'json',
success: function(result){   
         var end = new Date().getTime();
         var dur = end - start;
         console.log("millisecs passed",dur);   
           var  size = result.length;
           var content = '';
           var number = 1;
           if(size>0){
            document.getElementById('table').style.display="block";
           $.each(result,function(key,value){
               var num    = number++;
               content += '<tbody>';
               content += '<tr>';
               content += '<td>'+num+'</td>';
               content += '<td>'+value.Name+'</td>';
               content += '<td>'+value.UserId.toUpperCase()+'</td>';
               content += '<td>'+'<a href="#" onclick ="getJira(\'' + value.UserId + '\')">'+value.count+'</a>'+'</td>';
               content += '</tr>';
               content += '<tbody>';
           });

           $('#employee_table').append(content);

        }   
          ....There is one more table jiratable in a similar way.
```

Now I am getting the 2 tables displayed in a single page but how to display the input field in one page. And upon clicking submit button it should redirect to another page to display the tables. Please help me with this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please guys help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like this:

```html
// Simulate a mouse click:
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:
window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
```